# What are the benefits in casting an exception to more generic?

Tags: c#, exception, casting

Today I cam across the `Error` class in `System.Linq`. There are many Exceptions here (which are casted to the most basic one). For example:

```
internal static Exception ArgumentNull(string paramName)
{
  return (Exception) new ArgumentNullException(paramName);
}
```

It is used for example here:

```
public static List<TSource> ToList<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source)
{
  if (source == null)
    throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
  return new List<TSource>(source);
}
```

Why does some one decide to do it? Are there any benefits?

Comment: It made a C# programmer that did not understand OOP feel better.  That is all.   That he's not around anymore to ask is very rarely a coincidence.  Be careful to not be the meat that is thrown at a project disaster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nobody does that. I assume you're using a reflector to get a decompiled code from the final binaries - the reflector is to blame.

If you look at .NET reference source code, it doesn't do this:

```
public static Exception ArgumentNull(string argument)
{
  return new ArgumentNullException(argument);
}
```

Other similar pieces of code (it's a common pattern in the base libraries) also omit the explicit cast.

For completeness:

No, there's no point in doing the cast. If you insist and add the explicit cast, the compiler will remove it anyway. The only special case I can think of is if you're dealing with anonymous types or `var`, e.g.:

```
var ex = (Exception) new ArgumentNullException(...);
var someType = new { ex = (Exception)new ArgumentNullException(...) };
```

The first case is still silly - why not use `Exception ex` instead of `var`? The second is useful in certain cases.